# Google Oauth2 with Service account for Google Speech API rpc not working

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-speech-api

I am developing an android application, which uses Google Speech to text via the Google cloud streaming [Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) at the moment, however I am having trouble to get the authentication to work.

I want to authenticate at the Google Cloud API using OAuth2 and a authkey.json from a Google Service account.

I use the `SpeechGrpc.SpeechStub` class from package `google.cloud.speech.v1beta1` to call RPC methods. This needs a `ManagedChannel` in the constructor through which it communicates with the API.

I found an example showing how to create a `ManagedChannel` with `GoogleCrendential` here: [GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/grpc/src/main/java/com/examples/cloud/speech/StreamingRecognizeClient.java)

It worked until the point of intercepting the credentials into the channel. The `ClientAuthInterceptor` class, which is used in the example to intercept the credentials into the channel is

1. deprecated
2. takes only `com.google.auth.Credentials` as argument while `GoogleCredential` inherits from `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential`.

Next try: google example: [Using OAuth 2.0 with the Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)

It advises me to use a `Plus` to wrap the `GoogleCrendential`.
But the `Plus` is also `deprecated` and does not even contain
either a method

`builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)`

as shown in topic GoogleCredential on that page, nor a method

```
Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

As shown in section ServiceAccounts on that page.

I am running out of options as the  `SpeechGrpc.SpeechStub` class, which is used to call rpc methods, needs a `ManagedChannel` to work.

An other option could maybe be to add the credentials to the `SpeechGrpc.SpeechStub` and not to the `ManagedChannel` through the method

`SpeechGrpc.newStub(channel).withCallCredentials(CallCredentials creds)`

If this is possible, I would like to know, how I can create `CallCredentials` out of a Service Account's `authkey.json` file.

I read through every example, google documentation and thread on this topic I could find within the last weeks, but I don't get this authentication to work.

I hope anyone in here now can help me out of this confusing google api and library issue.

Comment: Any special reason you want to use a service account and oauth when this is a public api and you could just use an api key?

Comment: Well the api is public, yes but for streaming use case I pay with my account. In all documentation it is told that  one can use the api only through oauth ( <https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.Speech.StreamingRecognize> ). For me it doesn't matter which auth I use. Do u have a working solution with api key method?

Comment: Api key will identify your account. Oauth is for accessing private data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to add one line before your code starts. In the google-doc-sample case add it in main() method very first line.

**GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream());**

Also, refer this link. https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-java

After 0.6.0 release google moved their authentication under this:

google-auth-library-oauth2-http